# How to Kill the exe in taskmanager?

Tags: .net, windows, process, c#-3.0, exe

I generated the C#-Win App exe using visual studio setup project.
After closing the installed app,still process is running in task manager.
I tried with **Application.Exit()** in **Dispose()** of every form.
but while navigating one form to another form i used **this.Hide()**.so each navigation application closing.

i can't use **MDI** concept now..

How to do it?

Please guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies

In the each form **FormClosed** event handler i called the **Application.Exit();**

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();                
}
```

It's working great..

Answer (score 0):

In your last form handle the `Closing` event and then call [Envirunment.Exit](http://Terminates%20this%20process%20and%20gives%20the%20underlying%20operating%20system%20the%20specified%20exit%20code.), it will cause the same effect you want. So:

```
private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the main form `Form_Close` event handler you can have `Application.ExitThread()`